# Online collaborative text editing with auto scroll down option

Tags: text-editor, collaboration

I'm looking for something like Google Docs, but with an additional option: if someone typed a new word in the document, the app should scroll down there automatically.

Most we apps I've found supports collaborative text editing (as Google Docs), but they're designed for the case when both contributors would edit a part of the document at the same moment. I don't need that. One person will write, others will only read, hence this is important that the document window should follow what person#1 just wrote. If he wrote a lot of text, everyone should see the new lines too, without the need to manually scroll down. Google Docs doesn't support this, and I couldn't create a custom script.